# Having trouble understanding circuit diagram (paper touchpad)

Tags: arduino, capacitance

A few years ago someone posted a demo on youtube for a "paper trackpad" which is basically an alternative for your laptop mouse (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3b68vZQyIc)). This particular project uses Arduino as a microcontroller. Unfortunately, I was unable to get any schematics from the creator because the post was so old however, I did find a diagram of the circuit. 
[image]

I had a few questions (I am a completely new to electronics sorry). 
The capacitors being used in the diagram, are they for stabilizing the signal?
The wires A0, A1, A2, A3 are they being connected to the Arduino?

Can someone please offer their guidance?

This is the [link](http://hackaday.com/2010/11/16/paper-touchpad/) to the original project.

Comment: Your best bet might be to spend some time learning how ordinary resistive touchpads work.  Do note the comment thread at your link where the creator admits it was a bit of a joke, given that you get graphite all over your finger.

Comment: I hope my answer below helps. But I suggest you come up with a new title in the form of a relevant question as it makes your contribution much more useful content and will avoid having your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

> The wires A0, A1, A2, A3 are they being connected to the Arduino?

Yes. I don't think it is explicitly documented, but read the code and it is a safe conclusion:

```
  //read the four corners
  a = analogRead(0);
  b = analogRead(1);
  c = analogRead(2);
  d = analogRead(3);
```

> The capacitors being used in the diagram, are they for stabilizing the signal?

Yes, that's one way of putting it. Consider the circuit without the capacitors, and it represents simple voltage dividers that will (probably radically) disturb the analog inputs for every miniscule change in the finger-graphite-paper connection. The capacitor/2MΩ combinations are [RC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) that resist sudden voltage changes e.g. if the finger has pulled the input to ground and then released, the capacitor essentially "discharges" via the 2MΩ resistor at a rate indicated by the RC time constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped! I have been getting values for my project now but can't seem to derive a function for my x and y coordinates. Do u know how I could do this?

Comment: hand-made graphite paper is going to be quite wonky so I suspect a large dose of trial and error! A good place to start is probably take some measurements, write a set of simultaneous equations and solve them..